# Running shell script as admin using expect on OS X

Tags: bash, shell, expect, osx-yosemite

I am trying to let non-admin users run a script in a shared environment that requires root privileges. I was going to build either an AppleScript or Automator application that invokes expect in order to pass the login credentials (yes, I know the dangers, it will all be execute only). However I get the login to work, but the shell script I am trying to run doesn't seem to be executing, since it returns instantly. I am new to expect and I believe I have an error in my script. Ideas anyone?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 60
set password "MyPass"
set command "bash /Applications/mampstack-5.4.36-0/ctlscript.sh start"
eval spawn login admin
expect "assword:"
send "$password\n"
expect "$"
send  "$command\n"
expect "$"
send exit
expect "$"
send exit
```

Comment: expect really isn't the right tool for this job. If you have root, you can put a line in `/etc/sudoers` to allow users to run this script as your desired user with no password at all needed. Otherwise, you're exposing your password to the world in plaintext unless you jump through a separate privilege-escalation hoop to keep users away from being able to read the text of the script.

Comment: If you really wanted an expect answer, also -- expect scripts use TCL syntax, not bash syntax, so this should be tagged `tcl`, not `bash`.

Comment: ...but as a general rule, it's always better to do things in a way that doesn't require a password at all than to automate putting in a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it that way. Instead, edit `/etc/sudoers` to add the following lines (or, on a default config of MacOS, you can create a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` with the following content):

```
# allow use by GUI apps (AppleScript, Automator), which don't have a TTY
Defaults:%staff !requiretty

# on MacOS, all humans are members of the staff group
%staff ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Applications/mampstack-5.4.36-0/ctlscript.sh start
```

...then, have your AppleScript or Automator code run:

```
sudo -u admin /Applications/mampstack-5.4.36-0/ctlscript.sh start
```

...which will require no password at all.

Comment: I thought this was the greatest (read: simple & elegant) idea! But, I get the message "Execution by root not allowed" It needs to be run by a user with admin privileges, but not root. I still need to login as admin.

Comment: @Arana, then use `sudo -u the_username /Applications/mampstack-5.4.36-0/ctlscript.sh start`, substituting the actual target username for `the_username`.

Comment: Fabulous! It all works now. I even added status and stop, then put them into an Automator Applescript selector and passed them to run shell script and now users get to choose how they interact with ctlscript! Thanks a lot Charles!!